# ListView não está atualizando, Android

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Galera, tenho o código abaixo. Criei um `FloatingActionButton` que tira foto de todos os itens que estão na `ListView`, mas o método list.getChildAt(i).isEnable está retornando nullpointer. Alguma idéia pra resolver?

```
ListView list = JTaritronClientReportFragment.getInstance().getList();

list.setSelection(0);
int j=0;
while (j<list.getCount()) {
    int lastPosition = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLastVisiblePosition() - list.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {
        if (list.getChildAt(i).isEnabled()) {
            JUtil.saveScreenShot(list.getChildAt(i), "operadora" + j + ".png");
            j++;
        }
    }
    list.setSelection(lastPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o seguinte método:

```
    list.invalidateViews(); // Para atualizar a lista
```

E para atualizar o conteúdo caso o *invalidateViews()* não funcione e você tenha um Adapter:

```
    seuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Para atualizar o cursor da lista
```

Se essas alternativas não funcionarem visite esse post, pois é parecido com sua pergunta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview

Espero ter ajudado.

Obrigado

Comment: eu dei mais uma olhada no código e está atualizando só que o if (list.getChildAt(i).isEnabled()) está retornando nullpointer, vou mudar a pergunta

Comment: Ele está retornando null, provavelmente pois na sua lista no elemento getChildAt( i )  possa estar vazio.

Comment: eu acho q está retornando null pq não está aparecendo na tela, por exemplo, tenho uma listView com 6 itens, ele tira foto dos tres primeiros duas vezes, ai depois atualiza a tela